# O que é o float em Python?

Tags: python, float

Eu tenho o seguinte código em Python, mas não sei o que quer dizer o `float`.

```
peso = float(input('Digite seu peso (kg): '))
```

Comment: Hugo, você é iniciante, todos nós também fomos, e ainda somos, leia isto [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219211/qual-a-forma-correta-de-usar-os-tipos-float-double-e-decimal)  Independente da linguagem as respostas, contidas na pergunta, irão te ajudar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` pega uma entrada de teclado do usuário, e retorna uma string.

`'1.5'` seria a representação de um quilo e meio, porém esté entre aspas, caracterizando uma string, e caso esse valor seja usado em um cálculo matemático irá ocorrer um erro.

Agora passando essa string na função `float`, faz com que seja convertida para número flutuante e assim o cálculo matemático se torna possivel.

Answer (score 5):

Este `float()` é uma função que pega um valor qualquer passado para ela e tenta transformar em um valor do tipo `float`.

[O tipo `float` é um dos tipos numéricos disponíveis na linguagem Python nativamente](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex).

Este tipo permite guardar dados numéricos com parte decimal (o que vem depois da vírgula). [O problema é que ele não tem exatidão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). Para alguns problemas é ok trabalhar com um dado assim, para outros não é, por exemplo usar como valor monetário exige exatidão. Existem outros [tipos que podem aceitar parte decimal e um deles é exato](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

O tipo `float` é associado ao valor de um objeto armazenado na memória e tem um formato interno específico que é capaz de representar um valor fracionado. Note que em Python as variáveis não têm tipo (na verdade tem um único tipo, mas não se preocupe com esse detalhe teórico). A tipagem dinâmica faz com que uma variável aceite qualquer tipo de valor. Por isso sabemos que `peso` terá um objeto do tipo `float` ao final da execução da linha, já que está atribuindo o resultado retornado pela função `float()`. E como sabemos disto? Lendo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float).

Importante que pode acontecer um erro se a função não for capaz de criar um valor do tipo `float` de forma adequada e que faça sentido.

Então a função `input()` devolve sempre um objeto do tipo `string` com um texto digitado pelo usuário. O que a `float()` está tentando fazer é interpretar esse texto e fazer ele virar um número compatível com o tipo de ponto flutuante binário (ver *link* acima para mais detalhes). Se não der erro haverá um valor potencialmente decimal. Depois pode usar para operações matemáticas sem problema, não terá um texto que não permite fazer cálculos.

O fato de ser quilogramas não é suficiente para saber se precisa de exatidão ou não. Então só isso não ajuda decidir se é o tipo adequado. Para um exercício parece ok, porém saiba que isso pode ser um erro em outros cenários. Não treine o erro.

Answer (score 2):

Float é uma variável que representa os números reais. Ou seja, valores onde temos 1.7, 2.8, 2.5... entre outros.

No caso acima, a variável é float por se tratar de um valor em kgs para o usuário colocar seu peso.

A algum tempo atrás criei uma aplicação em Python para efetuar o cálculo do IMC, onde o usuário colocava seu peso e sua altura e o programa printava na tela seu IMC.

Comment: Por acaso estou também a tentar desenvolver uma calculadora de imc, obrigado ;)

Comment: Corrigindo a nomenclatura: `float` é uma classe nativa da linguagem para se trabalhar com ponto flutuante.

Comment: Concordo com a resposta de Anderson, só lembrando que ponto flutuante, são números fracionados que na matemática pertencem ao conjunto dos números reais. Caso precise de um exemplo, achei um script de um programa de calculo de IMC em Python:  
https://www.portugal-a-programar.pt/forums/topic/72919-resolvido-calculadora-de-imc/
Espero ter ajudado. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Números com um ponto decimal pertencem a um tipo chamado float, porque estes números são representados em um formato chamado ponto flutuante